# Error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I am experiencing an error and I can't figure out why.

I have a subclass: (Header)

```
    class motionSensor: public sensorLeaf
{
public:
    motionSensor(const int& sensorID, const int& sensorType, bool sensorActivate);
```

Which inherits from superclass "sensorLeaf"

The subclass has 2 private variables

`const float minDistance;
 const float maxDistance;`

In my class file; here is my constructor:

```
    motionSensor::motionSensor(const int &sensorID, const int &sensorType, bool sensorActivate)
 :sensorLeaf(sensorID, sensorType, sensorActivate), minDistance{1.0f}, maxDistance{5.0f}
```

But once I compile it, I get following error:

```
/home/jb/EmergencySensor/motionsensor.cpp:8: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
  :sensorLeaf(sensorID, sensorType, sensorActivate), minDistance{1.0f}, maxDistance{5.0f}
                                                                                        ^
```

Sensorleaf Constructor is :

```
sensorLeaf::sensorLeaf(const int sensorID, const std::string sensorType, bool sensorActivate)
{
    _sensorID = sensorID;
    _sensorType = sensorType;
    _sensorActivate = sensorActivate
}
```

With as private variables:

```
private:  
    int _sensorID;
    std::string _sensorType;
    bool _sensorActivate;

};
```

After doing some research I found that the error could occur when you define a string as ' ' and not " " but I have not used this anywhere so.

Comment: Show us the `sensorLeaf` constructor.

Comment: Please read the posting guidelines, in particular those about the minimal but complete example.

Comment: Updated, Im sorry :)

Comment: What is the type of `_sensorID`?

Comment: I found the mistake! in motionSensor, sensorType is of type "int", in sensorLeaf its of type "string". Haha. After explaining it I saw it myself.

Comment: @Jbv1 Remember that next time you'll want to ask a question like that :P

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to force a `const int &sensorType` from `motionSensor` constructor  to `const std::string sensorType` of `sensorLeaf` constructor.

```
 motionSensor::motionSensor(const int &sensorID, const int &sensorType, bool sensorActivate)
------------------------------------------------------------^
 :sensorLeaf(sensorID, sensorType, sensorActivate), minDistance{1.0f}, maxDistance{5.0f}
-----------------------^

sensorLeaf::sensorLeaf(const int sensorID, const std::string sensorType, bool sensorActivate)
-------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Thanks! I found it myself after :D

Comment: @Jbv1 I've no idea what change you made. Isolate the example into an SSCCE.